# Can I use a variable as index in for loop in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, chart.js

I have this for loop on my python template to fulfill an array of values:

```
labels: [{% for bftimes in dataBF.buffers.0.times %} "{{ bftimes }}", {% endfor %}]
```

I would like to know if I can use an *int* variable as an index instead writing it directly, as seen on the code above.

I need to use the index of the selected value of a dropdown:

```
//returns the index of the selected value
document.getElementById("buffer").selectedIndex
```

Comment: You can loop over an array and use {{ forloop.counter }} for indexing purpose.

Comment: Not sure I understand this question.  I think you want to use a javascript loop to enumerate the values in dataBF.buffers.0.times?  There would be a way to do that if times were just evenly spaced numbers up to some max.  But the javascript interpreter has no way to access the Python objects contents. It can only do javascript things with javascript. Can you make your question clearer?

Comment: I have an onChange call in my select that returns the index of its selected value. Then need to use it on my for loop "{% for bftimes in dataBF.buffers.0.times %}" instead of that zero value. For example "dataBF.buffers.SELECTED_VAL.times" which SELECTED_VAL is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question needs more context to help us understand your goal. It seems you are mixing python with javascript data structures.

My general recommendation is that you first prepare the python data structure to what you will need and then convert it to json. Looping within Django template language should be used only on simple cases.

If you use django>=2.1 you can use `json-script` template tag

```py
 {{ data|json_script:"my-data" }}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script

If not, you can use

```
# views.py
import json
def foo(request):
    dataBF = {"a": [{"c": [1,2,3,1,1]},{"d": [1,2,3,1,1]}]}
    # here you can manipulate the data accordingly to what you need
    data = json.dumps(dataBF)
    return render(request, "index.html", context={"data": data})
```

On the template side

```
<script>
    const datajs = {{ data | safe }};
</script>
```

The datajs is a javascript object that you can work with.

I've made an example that you can check https://repl.it/@IvanPereira/python-to-javascript-django-template

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 ways.

1. Store all values in a list, which JavaScript will consider as json array, and loop over using JavaScript itself. This way you won't be able to update records from server and all values that has to be looped over should be pre-fetched.
2. You can use AJAX call to pass the selected index from JavaScript and return the new array and update that in the template using JavaScript itself.